# proguard module-info and jlink

Tags: java, proguard, jlink, module-info

Proguard does remove module-info in default.

`keep 'class module-info'`

Force proguard to keep the module-info class but it does not update the references inside to the obfuscated names, therefore jlink fails with
`"Package x.y.z not found in module"`

Is there a way how to keep module-info but let proguard update it so that it corresponds to the obfuscated package names ?